# Erasing instruction from LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

What data structures should I modify while deleting an instruction from LLVM IR. Currently, I am using only 
I->eraseFromParent() method to do this. It gives me a StackDump error at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `eraseFromParent` is the right way to do this according to the [LLVM Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html). Did you replace the uses of the instruction by something else before erasing it, though?